# mfc CScrollView deactivate

Tags: mfc

i wanna make a notepad(windows8)

the notepad`s scrollbar is deactivate(When not needed)

but CScrollView is hide scrollbar(When not needed)

how to change CScrollView's scrollBar  like notepad's scrollBar?

Answer (score 0):

Style for multi-line edit control where vertical scroll bar is hidden unless there there is overflow:

`WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | ES_AUTOVSCROLL`

For Notepad style:

`WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | ES_VSCROLL`

When using dialog editor, set the values for `Auto VScroll` and `Vertical Scrollbar`, corresponding to `ES_AUTOVSCROLL` and `WS_VSCROLL`